Sript on an external file works but in the htmk file doesn't work
When I set the script on the head
<script src="/assets/js/timer.js" defer></script>

the script works properly.
But when I put the script directly in the HTML the script doesn't work
<script>
            const downloadBtn = document.querySelector(".download-btn");
            
            const fileLink = "<?php echo $article->file?>";

            const initTimer = () => {
                if(downloadBtn.classList.contains("disableTimer")) {
                    return location.href = fileLink;

                }
                let timer = downloadBtn.dataset.timer;
                downloadBtn.classList.add("timer");
                downloadBtn.innerHTML = `Your files will download in <b>${timer}</b> seconds`;
                const initCounter = setInterval(() => {
                    if(timer > 0) {
                        timer--;
                        return downloadBtn.innerHTML = `Your files will download in <b>${timer}</b> seconds`;
                    }
                    clearInterval(initCounter);
                    location.href = fileLink;
                    downloadBtn.innerText = "Se están descargando los archivos";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        downloadBtn.classList.replace("timer", "disableTimer");
                        downloadBtn.innerHTML = `<span class="icon material-symbols-rounded">vertical_align_bottom</span>
                                                <span class="text">Download again</span>`;
                    }, 3000);
                }, 1000);
            }
                
            downloadBtn.addEventListener("click", initTimer);
        </script>

I tried doing setting a link instead of the php but it doesn't work

put the script directly in the HTML - exactly where do you put this <script>?  Your script src= tag has defer so it's essentially the same as putting it directly before </body> - if your in-page script is not directly before </body> then it's not the same.

If you put it at begin of <body>, than your elements are not loaded on page yet, so JS does not find them. E.g. document.querySelector(".download-btn");

Besides the php part is not closed correctly <?php echo $article->file;?> (missing semicolon.
